# Converting TeX to word: linguistic text (linguex package)

Tags: msword, linguex, latex-to-word

I would like to collaborate with colleagues who do not use LaTeX and want a 'Track Changes' function. Therefore, I would like to convert my TeX files into Microsoft Word format. I tried `grindeq` and `tex2word` which both work up to the point where I use the first linguistic example.
I am using the `linguex` package for glossing, e.g.

```
\exg. word1 word-2.\label{gl:label1}\\
gloss1 gloss-2\\
'That's the translation' \hfill [\sc{name}]
```

With the programs I tried for one the formatting is not taken over (`word1` and `gloss1` and `word-2` and `gloss-2` are supposed to be aligned) and in `tex2word` the command for small caps (namely `\sc`) is interpreted for the whole following text (also some comments are printed and references don't work; in `grindeq` the tables don't look perfect)

Does anybody know of a program which is able to do this?
Thank you for any hints

Comment: you may try `tex4ht`.  the command for compiling to word is `mk4ht oolatex filename`. note that you probably can't get perfect result with any tool

Comment: One of the biggest advantages of LaTeX, namely its ability to provide custom support for specialized needs such as linguistics, is also one of its biggest weaknesses: tools that are designed to convert from LaTeX to other formats can't possibly know about all of the packages designed for that custom support.  But without knowledge of the packages, the converters are unlikely to be able to do an adequate job.